# Ubuntu 20.04 boot logo image directoy

Tags: 20.04, customization, plymouth

I would like to change this default ubuntu logo

[image]

But I can't find it. I tried to change

```
/usr/share/plymouth/ubuntu-logo.png
```

But that is the image on the login screen. Can you tell me how to change it or where is this file located?

update: I changed that image and it actually works.

Comment: The image is known as watermark.png in `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/spinner`

Comment: Found it. Thank you very much-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic search results that the ImageDir is `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/spinner`

```
[Plymouth Theme]
Name=BGRT
Description=Jimmac's spinner theme using the ACPI BGRT graphics as background
ModuleName=two-step

[two-step]
Font=Ubuntu 12
TitleFont=Ubuntu Light 30
ImageDir=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/spinner
```

[image]

It is not good idea to replace lot of Images of this spinner..

Instead find out a simple Plymouth theme which uses single Image and replace it..

If you want to change Ubuntu logo..

this is the Image file

```
/usr/share/plymouth/themes/spinner/watermark.png
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I changed that image and it actually works, but using Cubic to create a new ISO the image of the ubuntu logo continues to appear before the installation phase, while actually after the installation it vanishes for the "new" image. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

All plymouth data and config needs to be embedded inside initramfs to be applied in iso boot, so you need to apply:

`update-initramfs -u`

Try this and check the results.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to change 2 files:

```
/usr/share/plymouth/ubuntu-logo.png
/usr/share/plymouth/themes/spinner/watermark.png
```

And then update the initramfs as has been mentioned before:

```
update-initramfs -u
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering why changing the `watermark.png` file inside `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/spinner/` only changes the logo while shutting off but not while booting up, the reason is that while booting **up**, plymouth's bgrt theme uses the `ubuntu-logo.png` file located inside `/usr/share/plymouth/`