# How to change 20.04 default spinner

Tags: 20.04, icons, icon-themes

[image]

Please notice the spinner next to the text " Thunderbird Mail ". I replaced the spinner icon in

`usr > share > icons > Yaru`

`scalable-max-32 > status`

and in

`scalable > status`

both icons have name `process-working-symbolic`

Even after that, I get this old spinner everywhere. Is it possible to change it to an icon of our choice. ? Thanks.

Comment: For the changes to be picked up by the theme, either Gnome shell should be restarted via the _Run command_ dialog: Alt+F2 + press `r` + Enter; or, you could cycle (change) themes back and forth in the Settings app's Appearance tab.

Comment: I restarted the computer at least twice. Also, I modified the core theme. Do I have to change the icon theme through Tweaks ?

Comment: @Levente . just tried, switching icon themes has no impact on this condition

Comment: I don't know how to change that icon. All I know is that altering themes is frustrating and in the end, will never be just a small time-investment. It always ends up in loads of time killed into it. By now I try to change only those things that _really_ irritate me. The rest, I just put up with. It's a matter of whether it's worth the effort...

Comment: @user227495 how to reproduce the spinner? I mean from which/in which case the spinner appears?

Comment: @UnKNOWn I simply click to open Thunderbird from Favourites from the Side Panel and I can see the above action in top panel. Thanks.

Comment: The location of the icon used can be in different directories **not only**  `/usr/share/icons` depending on the source you installed Thunderbird from ie. snap, flatpak, apt ..... run `locate process-working-symbolic` to find out and change the icon in use accordingly.

Comment: @Raffa it is the same for all programs, Firefox, Thunderbird, Nautilus, Login through GDM etc. I will the `locate` option. Thanks.

Comment: @Raffa I can see some entries for Yaru inside Snap. I will try changing them. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I tried to change the symbolic icons in `Snap` folder by using `Open as administrator` in Nautilus. But I was not able to paste at all. Do you think I should CHMOD through Terminal ? If yes, what kind of permissions ?  I am afraid of using 777.

Comment: No, don’t. Use  `mount —bind` to test see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1036611). Probably if it woks you need to `mount —bind` after each reboot or remove snap installed apps and reinstall them with APT.

Comment: That is not something we should be doing, right ? I am quite happy the way my system is working right now. Except this spinner. Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing wrong about wanting to customize the look, feel or even functionality to your need. After all this is what open source mean. Snaps however require special handling but it might not work. See if this helps https://askubuntu.com/a/1268402

Comment: I am giving up for now. Kindly let me know how to distribute the bounty. Thanks.

Comment: "how to distribute the bounty." is up to you. If however nobody could come up with a better answer before the bounty period ends, I think @matigo answer shows some research and if he can update it with extra information from the comments above and other sources... I think it will be helpful to somebody in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Path of the Image in Question is hard coded as `'resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/process-working.svg'` and this is from the `.gresource` file being used.

This resource file could be different for login screen and desktop session.

Assuming you are using Default Ubuntu 20.04

you need to edit/replace the file `process-working.svg` from the `.gresource` file.

for Default Ubuntu 20.04 `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource` file is the one to edit.

I have gone through this process and replaced `process-working.svg` file with some .svg's and fell in a login loop.

the default `process-working.svg` file is like this.

[image]

and its properties are like this.

[image]

There seems to be a trick with svg images, Its a single svg image with different spinners. So I googled and got some 512 x 32 pixels with similar gnome-shell theme and could successfully change the spinner.

Getting/Creating the SVG is going to take much time.. So I used vanilla gnome's spinner and default Yaru's

Yaru's
[image]

Vanilla GNOME's
[image]

***Edit:***

have edited the original `process-working.svg` file with inkspace like this for testing purpose keeping the original size 512 x 32 px with svg format and tested it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

***For Automation Purpose, the below script can be used.***

Requirements

1. First keep your preferred .svg file (512px X 32px) `process-working.svg` in `/tmp` directory.
2. install the package `libglib2.0-dev` with below command

`sudo apt install libglib2.0-dev`

then save the below script in a plain text file as `pwsvg.sh` (process-working.svg)

```
#!/bin/bash

source="/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource"
backup=$source.BAK

pkg=$(dpkg -l | grep libglib2.0-dev >/dev/null && echo "yes" || echo "no")
if [ "$pkg" == "no" ]
then
echo "
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorry, the package 'libglib2.0-dev' is not installed. Install the package 'sudo apt install libglib2.0-dev' and then run this Script.
For now, Exiting...
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
exit 1
fi

cd /tmp

if ! [ -f "process-working.svg" ]
then
echo "-----your preferred .svg file 'process-working.svg' not found in /tmp folder. put the process-working.svg file in /tmp directory first.-----"
exit
fi

if [ "$UID" != "0" ]
then
echo "This Script must be run with sudo"
exit 1
fi

# take backup of original resource file
if ! [ -f $backup ]
then
cp $source $backup;
fi

for a in $(gresource list $backup); do
    b="${a/#\/org\/gnome\/shell\/}"
    mkdir -p $(dirname $b)
    gresource extract $backup $a > $b
done

mv -f process-working.svg ./theme/

FILES=$(find "theme" -type f -printf "%P\n" | xargs -i echo "    <file>{}</file>")

cat <<EOF >"theme/gnome-shell-theme.gresource.xml"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gresources>
  <gresource prefix="/org/gnome/shell/theme">
$FILES
  </gresource>
</gresources>
EOF

cd theme
glib-compile-resources gnome-shell-theme.gresource.xml
mv -f gnome-shell-theme.gresource $source
echo " Reboot to see the changes "
```

run the command `sudo bash pwsvg.sh` and reboot.

in case anything wrong, from any tty
replace the edited gresource file with the backup one which is `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource.BAK`

```
sudo mv /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource.BAK /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource
```

Tested in Ubuntu 20.04.2

Comment: Thanks. Just to be sure, I am ok with whatever comes before using the desktop. When we are inside, this spinner is a bit "lacks the charm" visually. The above solution modifies what comes within the desktop session, right ?

Comment: I tried to find the 512x32 image in Adwaita and Yaru-master without success. I am a bit inexperienced in editing the .gresource file. So I was holding it a bit. I will try to prepare my own SVG. Inkscape will be able to produce one. Are you the old, GDM wallpaper change expert PRATAP ? I would be happy to find the script which can edit the .gresource. Thanks.

Comment: Just found the source SVG in Yaru-master. They are in `yaru-master> gnome-shell> src`. I will try to make my own version out it. It will take some time.

Comment: since this is going to chat room, would it be possible to contact some other way ? Discord or email ? Only for this updates. Thansk

Comment: @user227495 Hi, when comments are more, We will automatically get the link to chat room here it self.

Comment: Allow me some time. I am trying to perfect my custom image. Thanks.

Comment: **+1** for this answer being direct to the point.

Comment: It is working now. Thanks. Will it be possible to help with the Plymouth spinner too ? Thanks.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1243458/739431 i think it gives some idea..

Comment: @UnKNOWn I have never tried Plymouth customisation. I have some ideas but do not know enough code to make it real.

Comment: @UnKNOWn Please see : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1315767/change-the-default-plymouth-spinner-in-20-04

Answer (score 2):

The icons are cached separately from their location, so any changes you make to a theme's assets will not be reflected until that cache is updated ... which can sometimes take years if you never apply updates to a system.

Fortunately, here's how you force the cache to rebuild:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Rebuild the cache:

   ```
   sudo update-icon-caches /usr/share/icons/*
   ```
2. There is no Step 2.

If this doesn't work ...

1. Update the timestamps of the theme directories:

   ```
   sudo touch /usr/share/icons/Yaru ~/.local/share/icons/Yaru
   ```
2. Use the `gtk-update-icon-cache` command:

   ```
   sudo gtk-update-icon-cache
   ```

Hopefully, you will see that Yaru's `process-working-symbolic` icon has been replaced with the icon you want to see

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried exactly as you described. I still see the old spinner though. I restarted the system to be sure, but the same. Tried cleaning using Stacer, but no luck. The local icon theme works and replaces the spinner in tabs when nautilus tab content takes time to load. Local icon theme is placed in `.icons`.

Comment: I tried all 3 commands, restarted thrice. Used Stacer to make sure. But I am still getting the old spinner :(